# How to write url to display all posts of certain type and taxonomy with given term_id

Tags: urls

I have an url that displays all posts with post_type=warning, like this :

```
<a href="?post_type=warning">All warnings</a>
```

I need an url that displays all posts with post_type=warning and  'taxonomy' ='warning_type',    'field' = 'term_id',  'terms' = 41. How can I do that ?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer, it is `<a href="/warning_type/red_warnings">Red warnings</a>` , where red_warnings is the slug for  term_id=41 (from table terms)